# How does Firebase read / write rules affect user experience on queries?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have read the Firebase docs, and am wondering how Firebase rules affect a user's experience within an app. Let's say you can only access a group if you are apart of that group as per your Firestore rules. So would you instead of querying all groups where member.uid == auth.uid ( like you would without rules), would you just query the "groups" collection, and the user would only receive the groups that they are apart of?

Every time I read about Firestore rules, they pretty much give the same example, without giving a sample of what the user would see if they queried the database. If someone could point me in the right direction of this, or show how I could test something like this, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So would you instead of querying all groups where member.uid == auth.uid ( like you would without rules), would you just query the "groups" collection, and the user would only receive the groups that they are apart of?

Firebase rules cannot filters data. You cannot have the client read an entire collection and then expect the rules to return a subset of the documents in that collection.

The reason for this is that listeners/observers are only validated once you attach them, after that they have access to the data. This is necessary in order to get the realtime update performance acceptable.

While you *can't* use rules to filter data, you *can* use them to validate queries. For an example of this, see the [Firestore documentation on securely querying data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query):

> ```
> service cloud.firestore {
>   match /databases/{database}/documents {
>     match /stories/{storyid} {
>       // Only the authenticated user who authored the document can read or write
>       allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Which rejects this query:

> ```
> // This query will fail
> db.collection("stories").get()
> ```

But allows this one:

> ```
> var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
>
> db.collection("stories").where("author", "==", user.uid).get()
> ```

You can see that we're essentially repeating the condition from the code in the rules. This allows you to securely expose a subset of the documents in a collection based on (for example) the user's UID.

Answer (score 0):

The firebase rules are there just to prevent spam in your application and also other stuff.

If you use `read:true` and `write:true` then anyone can read and write to the database, that is why it is better to use:

```
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
  }
 }
}
```

This way only authenticated users can see the data that is being retrieved from the database or can send data to the database.

If you have a users in a group and you used this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {

   // Match any document in the 'groups' collection
   match /groups/{group} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

It means all members of that group can read from that database, so if you are in that group, then the data will appear in your application.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure

Comment: So if you query for all groups, would only the ones that you are apart of show up, or would it throw an error?

Comment: Maybe you can add to your answer what would happen when a user tries to get root/groups instead of root/groups/groupID

Comment: It wont throw an error. The data is there in the database but it wont show it on the screen since the rules do not let it. @AndréKool: what do you mean? `Groups: { read: true`?

Comment: @PeterHaddad I'm talking about this part of the question: _"So would you instead of querying all groups where member.uid == auth.uid ( like you would without rules), would you just query the "groups" collection, and the user would only receive the groups that they are apart of?"_ I know in firebase you would get permission denied but i dont know if that is the same for firestore

Comment: @AndréKool he cannot do that it says this `All match statements should point to documents, not collections. A match statement can point to a specific document, as in match /cities/SF....` https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure